# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException unable to resolve

Tags: android, android-cursor

I am getting cursor index out of bounds "index 0 requested: with size 0". Its just a user registration and login application. When there is no user with matching Username and Password my application is getting crashed.

Below is the code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
final SUSQLiteHelper dbhelper = new SUSQLiteHelper(this);

LoginData login = dbhelper.readOneUser(loginuname.getText().toString(), loginpwd.getText().toString());

                if(login.getUname().toString().equals(loginuname.getText().toString()) && 
                        login.getPwd().toString().equals(loginpwd.getText().toString()))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successfull. Welcome " + login.getUname().toUpperCase() +" !".toString(), 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if(login.getUname().toString().equals(loginuname.getText().toString()) && 
                            !login.getPwd().toString().equals(loginpwd.getText().toString()))
                {                       
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed. Incorrect password !", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                      
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed. User doesn't exist !", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //it never goes here if no username is found in the table
```

**SUSQLiteHelper.java**

```
    public LoginData readOneUser(String uname, String pwd)
{
    SQLiteDatabase loginUserDB = this.getReadableDatabase();
    LoginData newLogin = null;
    Cursor cursor = loginUserDB.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{TABLE_ROW_UNAME, TABLE_ROW_EMAIL, TABLE_ROW_PWD}, TABLE_ROW_UNAME + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(uname)}, null, null, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        newLogin = new LoginData(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    }
    cursor.close();
    loginUserDB.close();
    return newLogin;
}
```

**LoginData.java**

This class has getter and setter methods for Uname, Pwd, Email fields and a constructor which takes these fields as arguments.

Comment: @ePeace here is my log ...

01-09 19:12:16.440: E/AndroidRuntime(308): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0`

It means that `cursor.moveToFirst() returns false` and `Cursor is empty`. So try to add the snippet for checking whether cursor is null or not and depends upon that modify your logic.

```
public LoginData readOneUser(String uname, String pwd)
{
 SQLiteDatabase loginUserDB = this.getReadableDatabase();
 LoginData newLogin = null;
 Cursor cursor = loginUserDB.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{TABLE_ROW_UNAME, TABLE_ROW_EMAIL,TABLE_ROW_PWD}, TABLE_ROW_UNAME + "=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(uname)}, null, null, null);

  if(cursor!=null) //Check whether cursor is null or not
  {
   if(cursor.moveToFirst())
   {
     newLogin = new LoginData(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
   }
  }
cursor.close();
loginUserDB.close();
return newLogin;
 }
```

---

```
  LoginData login = dbhelper.readOneUser(loginuname.getText().toString(), loginpwd.getText().toString());
  if(login!=null)
   {
     //check for incorrect username or password
    }
  else
   {
     //Notify that no Username available with these Username
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In function readOneUser(), check:

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst() && !cursor.isAfterLast()) {
     //
}
```